# How to request file with some post data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on bottle in which i have developed one application which force download one file if i pass it valid key in post data. Now in testing with python httplib library i get file in one variable but i need real file.
code for request is

```
import urllib2
url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/down/chrome.bin"
data = "7VXZ7vuxEpAGG9xi+LICMg"
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
f = urllib2.open(url, data)
print f.read()
```

Now i need real file not read it. So any solution for this also any solution for this ? My first priority is python.

Comment: you mean you need it in a file-like object, like StringIO ? in that case pass the data to it's constructor, like StringIO(f.read())

Comment: Are you asking how to structure a request to look like an HTML form file upload?

Comment: No i need to download file now i'm getting file in one variable but i want real file.

Answer (score 0):

We can use REST client extension in google chrome and mozila also [Request Library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) in python for this